# Is there a way to get text from the ngx-editor?

Tags: angular, ngx-editor

I am aware that `HTML` can be retrieved using `[(ngModel)]="htmlContent"`, but is it possible to get just the text? Thanks.

Example:

**This text is bold**. *This is italics*

html content: `<b>This text is bold</b>`.`<i>This is italics</i>`

text content: `This text is bold. This is italics`

[Raised github issue](https://github.com/Sibiraj-S/ngx-editor/issues/145)

Comment: If you could, you would lose any formatting. What is it you're looking to achieve?

Comment: @user184994 I know. I am working on a blog and want to save both, `text` and `html` of the created blog post in the database. I am saving `text` for the purposes of querying. Querying on `html` would not be accurate.

Comment: Can you please provide an example?

Comment: @SurjeetBhadauriya done

Comment: See the answer given by me.

Answer (score 4):

You can parse it with the `DOMParser` class, and then just use the `innerText` property.

Assuming you have the HTML in a variable called `html`, it would be

```js
let html = '<b>This text is bold</b>.<i>This is italics</i>';

var oParser = new DOMParser();
var oDOM = oParser.parseFromString(html, "text/html");
var text = oDOM.body.innerText;

console.log(text);
```

More about the parser can be found at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Parsing_and_serializing_XML

Comment: It is printing [object Object]

Answer (score 2):

yes!just use innerHTML property by following:

```
<div [innerHTML]="model.property"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are talking about this

1.-HTML file add ngModelChange:

```
<div class="NgxEditor__Wrapper">
     <ngx-editor-menu [editor]="editor"> </ngx-editor-menu>
     <ngx-editor
         [editor]="editor"
         [(ngModel)]="html"
         [disabled]="false"
         [placeholder]="'Ingresa el texto...'"
         (ngModelChange)="editorChange($event)"
      ></ngx-editor>
</div>
```

2.-Componente file.

2.1.- Import the class toHtml:

```
import { Editor, toHTML } from 'ngx-editor';
```

2.2.-Create the function to catch the event:

```
  editorChange(event: any){
    const htmlTexEditor = toHTML(this.html);
    console.log(htmlTexEditor);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
extractContent(htmlCode: string) {
        let span = document.createElement('span');
        span.innerHTML = htmlCode;
        return span.textContent || span.innerText;
    };
```

this might be useful to someone